# Selenium WebDriver and Grid 2

Tags: selenium, grid, webdriver

I try to run [Grid2](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2), but I don't understant basic thing.

I have the Hub, and I run on the hub machine the next command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role hub
```

I have a node, and I run on it the next command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Now, I want to run a test in Java that would execute **only** on the node (and not on the hub). But the code of the test is on the Hub machine. How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the hub and node on the same machine then yes, when you run your tests they will start on the node where your hub is located. In order to get around this you're going to need at least 2 machines, 1 to run your hub and 1 to run your node.

Start your hub on machine A then have your node register to the hub, when you start your tests on the hub machine it will automatically select an available node and run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where your code lies.  Your code communicates with the hub and tells it which node to execute the case on based on the desiredcapabilities object.

In your case as well, the case is running on the node only.  Hub just does the task of distributing it to appropriate node. Its just that the node is on the same machine as the hub, so you do not see a difference.